# Ora2PG REPLACE_AS_BOOLEAN property and exclude one column by replacing

Tags: postgresql, oracle, ora2pg

I'm using ora2pg to import an oracle db schema into a postgresql db schema. I configured all in the correct way and I'm able to dump the oracle dn into the postgresql db.

In the schema that I'm converting I have some columns number(1,0) that I need to convert as boolean in the pg schema.

At first I used this configuration
REPLACE_AS_BOOLEAN NUMBER:1
so every column with this type will be conmverted as boolean in the pg db.

The problem is that I have a column in the oracle schema defined as number(1,0). This column has to remain numeric and maintain the same type on the pg schema, so it hasn't to be converted as boolean.

This means that i changed the property in this manner
REPLACE_AS_BOOLEAN TABLE1:COLUMN1 TABLE2:COLUMN2 TABLE3:COLUMN3

I have a lot of columns that they have to be converted as boolean and the definition of this property became very long.

Is there a method to define the REPLACE_AS_BOOLEAN property to replace all the column with type number(1,0), but with some exception for one or some of them?

I had to wrote the property with the list of all the tables name and columns name

Comment: What about two migration scripts/configurations? One for only that specific table and one for the rest?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It can be a path to take a look. I need to check if is is possible to setup the configuration in a manner that I can export only one table in one project and in the other I can export all the tables except one. Hope that it is possible. I'll check. Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I applied the creation of two script and it worked. Thanks for the help